# Many appdomains for a web application in under iis7

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, castle-monorail

I have a monorail web application running on iis7. It appears like two concurrent requests are handled on two different appdomains! As far as I know, each application should have one appdomain and multiple httpapplications to handle requests...

Is there something I am missing? (configuration perhaps?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was writing output files to a folder in the bin directory of the web application. Since this folder is watched, it caused the application pool to recycle and that's why the second request was handled on a different (new) appdomain.

For some reason I thought that only web.config, global.asax are watched...

Comment: any changes to the bin-folder usually triggers a recycle. Keep in mind also that if you create folders in any location under your site-root, it will also recycle.

Answer (score 2):

See you found the solution yourself :)

Asp.net watches a lot of directories and files for different actions, that will cause the appdomain to unload. (global.asax, web.config, BIN, App_Code ++)

If you want more information, take a look at this blog on msdn 
blogs.msdn.com/tmarq/archive/2007/11/02/asp-net-file-change-notifications-exactly-which-files-and-directories-are-monitored.aspx